Prove that there are correct words of any length.
This is problem 9.103 from A path to combinatorics for undergraduates.
An alphabet consists of three letters. Some sequences of letters of length two or more are prohibited, and all of the prohibited sequences have different lengths. A word is a sequence of letters of any length. A correct word does not contain any prohibited sequences. Prove that there are correct words of any length.
Here is my attempt
Let $A=\{a,b,c\}$ be the three-letter alphabet. Any word of length $1$ is correct. Since there are $3^2$ words of length two and at most one sequence of letters of length two that is prohibited, one of the $3^2$ words must be correct. Pick a correct word $xy$ of length two. Since there are at most one sequence of letters of length two and at most one sequence of letters of length three that is prohibited, and there are three letters in $A$, there must exist a letter $z\in A$ such that the word $xyz$ is correct.
I am stuck on showing a correct word of length $n$ exists for any $n\ge 4$.
Any help is appreciated. Thank you.
Edit: Some of my new partial progress
Suppose we are given a word $s_1s_2s_3s_4s_5$ over the alphabet A. If $s_1s_2s_3s_4s_5$ is a correct word, then we are done. Suppose $s_1s_2s_3s_4s_5$ is not a correct word. Pick a letter, say $t_5$, such that no subsequence in $s_1s_2s_3s_4t_5$ is a bad subsequence of length $1$ or length $5$ that ends in $t_5$. Note that changing any of the first $4$ letters in $s_1s_2s_3s_4t_5$ cannot create a bad subsequence of length $1$ or length $5$ that ends in $t_5$. Pick a letter $t_4$ such that $s_1s_2s_3t_4t_5$ doesn't contain a bad subsequence of length $2$ or $3$ that ends in $t_5$. Now, any bad subsequence in $s_1s_2s_3t_4t_5$ must be contained in $s_1s_2s_3t_4$. Pick a letter, say $t_1$ such that no subsequence of length $1$ or $2$ in $t_1s_2s_3t_4$ starts with $t_1$. Pick a letter, say $t_2$ such that no subsequence of length $3$ or $4$ in $t_1t_2s_3t_4$ starts with $t_1$. Now, any bad subsequence in $t_1t_2s_3t_4$ must be contained in $t_2s_3t_4$. Pick a letter $t_3$ such that no bad subsequence in $t_2t_3t_4$ starts with or ends with $t_3$. Now, $t_2t_3t_4$ contanis no bad subsequence. It follows that $t_1t_2t_3t_4t_5$ contains no bad subsequence. So $t_1t_2t_3t_4t_5$ is a correct word of length $5$. We also obtain a correct word $t_1t_2t_3t_4$ of length $4$.
Now I tried to generalize the above argument for words of length $n\ge 6$ but there's just not enough letters in A to generalize it.
Edit: existence of correct word of length $n=6$.
Let $s_1s_2s_3s_4s_5s_6$ be a letter of length $6$, where the $s_j$ are letters to be determined. Note that in any words of length $6$, there is at most $1,2,3$ bad subsequence of length $6,5,4$ respectively. Moreover, any subsequence of those lengths must contain the $3^{th}$ and $4^{th}$ positions. We have $3^2$ choices for pair of letters $s_3s_4$. Pick letters $t_3t_4$, such that $t_3t_4$ is not a bad subsequence of length $2$ and $s_1s_2t_3t_4s_5s_6$ has no bad subsequence of length $4,5$ or $6$. Pick a letter $t_2$ such that $t_2t_3$ and $t_2t_3t_4$ are not bad subsequences. Pick a letter $t_5$ such that $t_4t_5$ and $t_3t_4t_5$ are not bad subsequences. Pick a letter $t_1$ such that $t_1t_2$ and $t_1t_2t_3$ are not bad subsequences. Pick a letter $t_6$ such that $t_5t_6$ and $t_4t_5t_6$ are not bad subsequences. $t_1t_2t_3t_4t_5t_6$ is a correct word of length $6$.

My suggestion would be to do an inductive proof.  You have proved it for the base clause now just use P(n) → P(n+1)

Initially I thought of doing an inductive proof, but I don't know how to do one.

We only need to show it in the limit as $n \to \infty$. I was trying to use Jackson-Goulden clustering method to deduce something about the generating function but got stuck...

I'm not sure if using Jackson-Goulden clustering method here is feasible since we don't know what the bad words are exactly.

@19021605 Yes, that's true. I was wondering if there's something like a worst case of no overlap. But haven't even got to testing it...

Define $a_0=1$ and let $a_n$ be the number of correct words of length $n$ for $n\ge 1$.
For $2\le k\le n$ ,define $b_k^n$ to be the number of words $Z$ satisfying the following conditions:
($1$) $Z$ is of the form $XY$, where $X$ is a correct word of length $n-k$ and $Y$ is a bad word of length $k$,
($2$) the word obtained from deleting the rightmost letter of $Z$ is a correct word.
Given any good word of length $n$, there are $3$ ways to obtain a word $W$ of length $n+1$ by adding a letter to its rightend. Note that $W$ is either a correct word or a bad word satisfying conditions ($1$) and ($2$). So we have
$$3a_n=a_{n+1}+\sum_{k=2}^{n+1}b_k^{n+1}$$
Note that given any bad word $W$ of length $n+1$ satisfying ($1$) and ($2$), we may remove its $k$ rightmost letters to obtain a correct word of length $n+1-k$. This process is clearly injective. So we have $b_k^{n+1}\le a_{n+1-k}$. So we have
$$3a_n\le a_{n+1}+\sum_{k=2}^{n+1}a_{n+1-k}$$
$$a_{n+1}\ge 3a_n-\sum_{k=1}^na_{n-k}$$
We now prove $a_{n+1}\gt 2a_n$.
We proceed by induction. The claim is clearly true for $n=0$ and $n=1$. Assume the claim is true for all $k\le n$. Then
$$\begin{align}
a_{n+1}&\ge 3a_n-\sum_{k=1}^na_{n-k}\\
&\gt 3a_n-\sum_{k=1}^n2^{-k}a_n\\
&\gt (3-\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}2^{-k})a_n\\
&=2a_n
\end{align}$$
It follows that $a_n\gt 2^n$ for $n\ge1$. Hence there exists correct word of any length.
